# Make img break from paragraph max-width restriction

Tags: css

I have a basic web page. Here's a demo so far: http://jsfiddle.net/ysuzL3n3/

The code generated from my CMS adds a paragraph tag around my img tag.

Is there a way to force `max-width:100%` on `<p><img src...` so it will work like the last image does on the demo?

**Code:**

```css
p {
    max-width:200px
}

img {
    max-width:100%
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent aliquet tortor eu aliquam sodales. Cras non nisi in sem egestas placerat.</p>
<p><img src="http://placehold.it/1400x400" /></p>
<img src="http://placehold.it/1400x400" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
p {
    max-width:200px
}

img {
    max-width:100%;
}
p img{
    max-width:100vw;
    width:auto;
}
body{
    margin:0;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent aliquet tortor eu aliquam sodales. Cras non nisi in sem egestas placerat.</p>
<p><img src="http://placehold.it/1400x400" /></p>
<img src="http://placehold.it/1400x400" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
p img {
    max-width:100%
}
```

Comment: I have tried this here: http://jsfiddle.net/ysuzL3n3/2/ but unfortunately it doesn't do what I want to achieve. I need to restrict text to 200px width and still show 100% of the image.

Comment: maybe you should try to change the width of that p :)

Comment: are you looking for something like this https://jsfiddle.net/jameshwartlopez/bkbwL92x/2/

Answer (score -1):

Change the following:

```
p {
    max-width: 200px;
}

p img {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/ysuzL3n3/1/ but unfortunately it doesn't fix my issue. The first image is still restricted to the paragraph and the 2nd image creates a horizontal scrollbar :(

Comment: Ah, it needs a `width: auto;`